# Mongoid Embedded Documents Adding / Removing With Minimum Hits to the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a a model "Entry" that has many items "Items" that are embedded documents:

```
class Entry
  embeds_many :items, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end
```

the issues is i have to move a bunch of embedded document Items around deleting some, add others, and moving others between Entrys. It seems like any operation I do on an Entry.items like:

```
entry.items << item or entry.items.delete(i)
```

causes its own database write. And if i'm making many changes that seems very expensive. Is there a way to tell mongoid to let me add items, remove them, move them locally and only when everything is done send a single entry.save! write to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the items array by doing:

```
entry.items = new_items
```

Is the most database efficient. But it turns out is buggy, make sure you have the latest version of mongoid and do an entry.save if entry.changed? || entry.new_record? because it occasionally wont save entry above when you modify the items.